# Analysis method for comparison of means in zero-inflated non-paired continuous data

Tags: mean, continuous-data, zero-inflation

I am currently doing my first project involving a lot of statistics and I've stumbled into a bit of a problem.

I am researching if comments from two different subreddits explainlikeimfive (ELI5) and AskReddit (AR) are different in the amount of metaphors they use. I've used a model called FrameBERT(https://github.com/liyucheng09/MetaphorFrame) to detect conventional/borderline metaphors (BD) and novel metaphors (NV) for each comment. (A conventional is a broad definition, while novel is a stricter definition).

I have 484 comments from ELI5 and 946 from AR. To account for longer answers on ELI5, I have divided the detected BD and NV with the amount of tokens in the comment. I have a lot of comments with 0 detected BD's and NV's (~180(AR-BD), (~500(AR-NV), (~150(ELI5-NV), which is what "zero-inflated"-means right?

My question is: How/what test do I compare the mean BD (or NV) per token between the two subreddits with?

So far I've used the Mann-Whitney U test since the data is not normally distributed. I've read somewhere that a Poisson Regression can be used, but that is only for count data right?

[image: Histograms of BD and NV per token distributions in ELI5 and AR respectively]

Any more info needed let me know!
Kind Regards,
Niels